PowerPoint to PDF fonts colour is wrong
I'm trying to export a PowerPoint document to PDF. I'm using foxit reader. When opening the PDF document the colour of the fonts changes from white to black (in the ppt I'm using white fonts, Arial).
I tried other things like Save as, or Print, or Embed fonts in the file and few more but none of it worked.
I am using the latest version of Foxit and PowerPoint.
In the end, I installed Acrobat Reader and the fonts were ok (white). Any idea why Foxit changed the fonts colour and how could I fix this?
Windows 11.

If the same PDF reads correctly in Acro Reader but not in Foxit, it would seem to be a Foxit problem, not a PowerPoint issue. I'd see if they have some kind of support forum, but also check to see if there might be preferences/options settings that would affect this, especially accessibility settings.

Yes, it seems to be a Foxit problem. I'll ask in their forum and I'll update the post here accordingly


The PDF may not have been exported properly. Did you use Windows Print to PDF? 2. You can try another of the many PDF readers and editors, such as free Sumatra PDF or freemium PDF-XChange Editor, if you prefer.


Acrobat is the gold standard. If it displays the PDF properly but a third-party reader doesn't, the problem isn't likely in the PDF. It would be useful to know what the problem is with Foxit; Adobe Reader has gotten to be a slow, annoying piece of advertising-ware. Print to PDF might make Foxit happier but if there are any hyperlinks in the original PPTX, they won't be live in the PDF, where they WILL if PPT's own Save as PDF feature is used.
